# Are the cost-path and least-cost-path tags synonyms?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't have the rep to propose these two tags as synonyms, nor am I certain whether or not they should be. The cost-path tag description seems to be quite specifically geared towards the ArcGIS tool. Perhaps it should be more general?

Comment: You might want to check out the thread at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms.

Comment: @whuber There's been some discussion on use of that thread. Specifically the currently accepted answer (resulting from some of that discussion, which also takes place at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/should-answers-on-how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-be-deleted-once-implemented) indicates new questions should be asked for each proposed synonym.

Comment: @Chris Thank you for bringing that discussion to our attention. I don't see a currently accepted answer there (FWIW), nor do I see more than three votes, so we cannot take that discussion (yet) as reflecting the sense of the community. I do see merit in opening a thread for each suggestion and then deleting it once it is resolved. That is more manageable than an ever-growing single thread (which becomes unwieldy for those who can see all the old deleted answers).

Comment: @whuber - since the asker accepted his own answer (this is in the suggesting question you linked to, not the additional one I linked to), it will not float to the top (this confused me at first too, til I read up on that, and kind of ruined my answer intention at the other question). You might find it easier by sorting according to answer date or activity, but there is one there.

Comment: @Chris I hope that after moderating two SE sites for four years I have some grasp of the mechanics :-).  Are we talking about the same thing?  You linked only to http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3761/should-answers-on-how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms-be-deleted-once-implemented and there is only one answer there--yours. The OP did not answer at all.

Comment: @whuber miscommunication apparently - I edited my comment to try and clarify but you'd already follow-up commented. :) The accepted answer in question is at http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3077/how-to-suggest-tag-synonyms

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Least-cost-path" was applied to exactly one thread (and "cost-path" to 62 of them).  I made the former a synonym of the latter.

Comment: So I'm confused what the outcome of the discussion was. Should I delete this question now that it's been resolved?

Comment: @whiteboxdev In a case like this one, where there was only one question using the tag, the general SE direction is to just edit the post yourself, remove the tag and change it to the one it should be. I can understand not wanting to make that call or having a question about it though - I have the same thoughts/concerns on [tag:digital-cartography] and [tag:cartography], though the former only has four questions. I haven't raised the issue yet. And regarding your new comment, you shouldn't - I'm not even sure you can once there's an up-voted answer (let alone accepted).

Comment: @ChrisW Thanks that helps.

Comment: @Chris It might nevertheless be preferable to favor the synonymizing process, because it deals automatically with all future attempts to use the same alternative tag.

Comment: Yes, that's definitely one of the upsides. The discussions I've read seem to indicate it's a question of whether the synonym is likely to be used. As mentioned elsewhere, different sites have different policies, and sometimes what works well in one place doesn't in another.